# User Accounts window doesn't allow any hotkey

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

I want to create a hotkey when `ahk_class #32770` windows are active, in my case, the User Accounts window opened by typing `netplwiz` in the Run. But, it seems that no hotkey works.

Here's what I did:

```
#NoEnv 
#Warn  
SendMode Input 
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% 

SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; A window's title can contain WinTitle anywhere inside it to be a match.
 
#ifwinactive
    #e::Run,%A_AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
        ;this doesn't work for ahk_class #32770, so I make the following workaround: 

#if winactive("ahk_class #32770") or winactive("ahk_exe explorer.exe")
    #e::Run,%A_AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
        ;but neither does this work. So I made the following test: 
    ^p::msgbox,hi
        ;and it doesn't work.
```

Did I do something wrong, or any workaround?

Comment: Which window do you expect to be of the class `#32770`? The file explorer Window? And on which Windows version?

Comment: I tested with with some types of `ahk_class #32770` windows, a "save as" window from Chrome, from microsoft word, and found that their being active doesn't affect any hotkeys. User Accounts window does affect, so I change the question title to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. End/Close the context with

**#if** or **#ifwinactive** as appropriate, if you have not.

Like in

#ifwinactive ahk_class #32770

#e::Run,%A_AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent

`#ifwinactive`

#if winactive("ahk_class #32770")

#e::Run,%A_AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent

`#if`

Comment: True. I just tested with a "save as" window being active, a ahk_class #32770 window, which doesn't affect any hotkey function. So, it seems that ahk_class #32770 isn't necessarily the source of problem. But in my case, it's the User Accounts window that does affect all hotkey functions. I probably should rename the question.